# 5.1 Speakers to Motherboard

Tags: connection, speakers, 5.1

I bought a motherboard that has 5.1 surround sound output 
(Optical, spdif, 3.5mm: C/S, L/R, SL/SR)

I have an old surround sound DVD player with NO digital inputs :( [panasonic 950t] I'm thinking of throwing out the DVD player and keeping the speakers.

The speakers just have bare wire.

What do I need to hook it up?

I presume a 5.1 amplifier. However I cannot find any. All the ones I see have tuners, DVD players, and a bajillion inputs.

I want a nice, simple, small 5.1 amplifier that will allow me to hook 5.1 speakers to a PC. Does such a product exist? Is that even what I need?

Comment: A picture of the cable would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will never be connecting those speakers directly to the computer, you will need an amplifier.  But I don't know of any that are not meant for home AV, and will be dvd player sized with a number of inputs.

However there's another issue, it sounds like you had one of those all in one kits, so you'll need to check what amperage (measured in Ohms) usually 4 or 8 the speakers are, and make sure they match.

In the end you're either better off getting a new all-in-one kit, or a PC specific 5.1 speaker kit.